# Xcode OSX Server "Internal Error Creating Bot"

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server, xcode-bots

I am trying to create a bot using OSX Server 4.0 and Xcode 6.4.

My project encompasses multiple repositories and uses additional libraries as submodules. When I go to "Product > Create Bot," A dialog appears, saying "Provide repository credentials for this bot."

The dialog shows all of the repositories which I use as submodules. If I attempt to authenticate them by either SSH or https, xcode rejects my credentials.

When I click "Ignore" and finish the setup process, it says "Bot creation failed with error: Internal Error Creating Bot" and gives me no other information.

As a test, I have successfully created a sample project in github which I can create a bot for without a problem. I have tried to add submodules to the sample project and it still can create bots fine.

Can anyone help fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer.

The problem ended up being GitSlave (http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/) which my team was using to keep our repositories updated. Something about the way GitSlave set up the repositories causes Xcode bots to fail with an internal error.

My issues accessing the repositories were unrelated to the internal error and were fixed by creating a new set of SSH keys for the bot instead of using my personal SSH keys, which had different permissions.

Hope this helps anyone else having this problem!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get past the "provide credentials" dialog, but Xcode Bots would fail with the same "Internal Error Creating Bot" error once I had stepped all the way through the wizard and clicked "Create".

The solution in my case was to change the remote.origin.url setting for my repository from a git@github.com SSH URL to a https://github.com HTTPS URL, and suddenly it just worked.

*(This is kind of maddening because I checked every log file and every place where there might be an error report and found nothing. Figured it out through trial and error)*